# Ruby Date.strptime difficulties with Cucumber/Rspec

Tags: ruby, date, rspec, cucumber

I have a ruby class that parses a date string using following format.

```
Date.strptime("01 01 2010","%d %m %Y")
```

The problem is, when I pass the string '01 01 2010' using Rspec I need to require 'Date' in order parse date properly and make examples pass
where my cucumber examples fails for the same string '01 01 2010'.

If I remove 'require Date' from the ruby class my Rspec examples fails while my cucumber examples passes successfully.

ruby version -1.9.2p180, rails version -3.1.0

How do I solve this to pass both Cucumber/Rspec examples?

Comment: This problem solved when ruby/rails updated to versions - ruby 1.9.3p0 and rails Rails 3.2.1